# Django model inheritance creating or get from parent

Tags: django

Am trying to build a project and it seems that using model inheritance for my requirements can work the best, I have one base model in which I have several model uses it for inheritance. In the base model, I have a slug field which is unique across all (for integrity)

In my child model, sometimes I want to create a record but if a parent already exists, I want to create only the child and link to the parent directly. for example,

```
class Base(models.Model):
   slug = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), unique=True)
   #Other fiels

class ChildA(Base):
   height = models.CharField(max_length=100, )

class ChildB(Base):
   is_for_sale = models.BooleanField(_('Is active'), default=True, )

# when creating ChildA, it will automtically insert into base model as well
ChildA.objects.create(slug='bmw', height='11')

# now for childB, I want the newly created object to link to an existing record in Base where slug
# is the unique value, is it possible todo such a thing?
ChildB.objects.create(slug='bmw', is_for_sale=True)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I want the newly created object to link to an existing record`? Do you need a foreign key maybe?

Comment: yup, I want it to behave like a foreign key. Because sometimes in ChildB, I want to link to an existing Base record. This way, I make sure I have always one record in Base as well as inherit all attribute in ChildB

Comment: Am not quite sure if thats possible to start with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might have misunderstood inheritance at this point.

If I get it right, you say that slug must be unique. Therefore you restrict the amount of Classes with a certain slug to '1'

Your Classes `ChildB` and `ChildA` are not "linked" to `BaseClass`, but are descendants of BaseClass, therefore an instance of a child is also an instance of `BaseClass`.

To me it seems you a looking for a relation between a Slug Object and multiple other Objects with different properties.

Instead of trying to derive from Class Base I would suggest a relation like:

```
class ChildA(models.Model):
   height = models.CharField(max_length=100, )
   slug = ForeignKey(Base)
```

This will ensure that the right Slug Object will be used and not created again.

If you need to keep that line of inheritance, keep your base class, but extract the slug field into its own class like

```
class Slug(models.Model):
 slug = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), unique=True)

class Base(models.Model):
  # all your other fields
  slug = ForeignKey(Slug)

class ChildA(Base):
   height = models.CharField(max_length=100, )
class ChildB(Base):
   is_for_sale = models.BooleanField(_('Is active'), default=True, )
```

Once you are here you can use the constructor of these classes to enforce further restrictions on Slug if they are not yet provided

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a set of common attributes, you want to make your [base model abstract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes), otherwise django will create a table for it.

If instead you are interested in a relation among all subclasses of `Base`, then you have to give up on inheritance and use a foreign key from every child to `Base`:

```
class ChildA(models.Model):
    base = ForeignKey(Base)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```